# Blockadblock script not working on blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger, adblock

blockadblock.com script not working on my website. "*https://mycodeenote.blogspot.com*" .
I am using simply blogger template . It is not outputting any console messages and error's.
I tried to include jquery but also not helped. why it's not working can someone explain?. Thank you for help.

[image]

Comment: nobody knows? please

Comment: can you share your blog link

Comment: https://mycodeenote.blogspot.com

Comment: it works on my end (i'm using uBlock origin), maybe it didn't detect the adblocker you are using.

Comment: thanks i resolved it by changing Advanced Detection Options -> Add special element defense.